# Moveit octomap plugin not updating planning_scene

Tags: moveit, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to write an `OccupancyMapUpdater` plugin that takes a full (or binary, I don't really care which one it is) octomap from an external topic and feed it to the planning scene.

Right now, I'm doing it by clearing the octree of the `OccupancyMapMonitor` and then feeding it the message's data:

```
 void ExternalOctomapUpdater::octoMsgCallback(const octomap_msgs::Octomap::ConstPtr& octo_msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("Received a new octomap message");
  if (monitor_->getMapFrame().empty())
    monitor_->setMapFrame(octo_msg->header.frame_id);

  tree_->lockWrite();
  tree_->clear();
  octomap_msgs::readTree<octomap::OcTree>( tree_.get(),*octo_msg);
  tree_->setResolution(octo_msg->resolution);
  tree_->unlockWrite();

  tree_->triggerUpdateCallback();
}
```

I basically copied the `PointCloudOctomapUpdater` code and replaced the references to point cloud with octomaps :)

The plugin compiles, is recognised by ROS and moveit does executes it.
I've setup some debug lines (removed here for clarity).
They tell me that the callback function is called and `tree_` gets cleared and updated: the number of leaves changes with the size of the octomap.I've also made sure that the resolution is right.

But with all that, the planning scene remains empty.
There is no error message, no crash, nothing, but the planning scene in rviz is blank and nothing gets published on the planning_scene topics.

I have probably forgotten to call some update function or something but I can't figure what and where.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265409/moveit-octomap-plugin-not-updating-planning_scene/) by [Notou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30947/notou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a while of fiddling I now have it working!

I still don't really know how the thing works behind the scene but it seems the planning scene only handles binary octomaps.

I was subscribing to a octomap_full topic and when I tried listening to a octomap_binary one it started working.

This line is nor even needed:

```
tree_->setResolution(octo_msg->resolution);
```

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/265024/moveit-with-octomap-from-slam-package/) for context and results.

---

Originally posted by [Notou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30947/notou/) with karma: 23 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0